# Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.2.1

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm trying to build a project using batch file, and ran into this error:

[INFO] Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.2.1

I do have maven version 2.2.1 installed on my computer. If I run "mvn -version" it shows maven 2.2.1.

Comment: Really you are using Maven 2.X ? 5 Years EOL / 10 Years no release? ca. 9 Years Maven 3.X is there.. Really need to use Maven 2.X?

Answer (score 1):

Maven-Eclipse-Plugin is retired and should not be used anymore.

Maven 2.2.1 is even worse.

Upgrade and try again.